# Unexpected segmentation fault encountered in worker when using Pytorch Geometric to load dataset

Tags: python, pytorch, segmentation-fault, pytorch-dataloader, pytorch-geometric

I encounter the following error when using DataLoader workers to load data.
I am using [NeighborSampler in PyG](https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/blob/master/torch_geometric/loader/neighbor_sampler.py) as "loader" in run_main.py line 152 to load custom dataset, and use `num_workers` of `os.cpu_count()`.

```
ERROR: Unexpected segmentation fault encountered in worker.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1134, in _try_get_data
    data = self._data_queue.get(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 107, in get
    if not self._poll(timeout):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 257, in poll
    return self._poll(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 424, in _poll
    r = wait([self], timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 931, in wait
    ready = selector.select(timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/selectors.py", line 415, in select
    fd_event_list = self._selector.poll(timeout)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/signal_handling.py", line 66, in handler
    _error_if_any_worker_fails()
RuntimeError: DataLoader worker (pid 1096707) is killed by signal: Segmentation fault.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_main.py", line 152, in train
    for step, _ in enumerate(loader):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 652, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1330, in _next_data
    idx, data = self._get_data()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1296, in _get_data
    success, data = self._try_get_data()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1147, in _try_get_data
    raise RuntimeError('DataLoader worker (pid(s) {}) exited unexpectedly'.format(pids_str)) from e
RuntimeError: DataLoader worker (pid(s) 1096707) exited unexpectedly
```

I am using Pytorch 1.12.0+cu116, one NVIDIA TITAN Xp GPU, CUDA version of 11.6, and Python version of 3.8.10.

I've searched a lot for this error, and found following solutions. However, they were all unhelpful.

- Using `num_workers` of 0 or 1. When I run with `num_workers` of 0, it results in "corrupted double-linked list" error. When I set `num_workers` as 1, the same error (Unexpected segmentation fault encountered in worker) still occurs. Actually, I don't want to lessen `num_workers`, because I am working on a pretty large dataset and lessening `num_workers` is a much slower option.
- Increasing shared memory size. I've done this by adding `none /dev/shm tmpfs defaults,size=MY_SIZEG 0 0` line in `/etc/fstab` and running `mount -o remount /dev/shm`. I've set MY_SIZE exactly as the size of main memory (which was previously 50% of main memory).
- Changing Python version to <= 3.6.9. I've tried this, but the same error still occurs.
- Checking that Python and dataset are mounted on the same disk. I've already verified that they are mounted on the same disk.

I've been struggling to fix this issue for several days, but I can't find the right solution, and it really makes me frustrated. Could you please help me out?

Comment: I've figured this out. I was using a customized, synthesized dataset expanded from an existing dataset. I've re-synthesized the dataset and the error disappeared when applied on this new dataset. I'm not sure why, but it seems that the previous dataset was corrupted in some way.

Comment: I get a similar segmentation fault using the PyG DataLoader, but my kernel crashes completely. So do I understand you correctly, you were not able to reproduce the error?

Comment: Okay, I could fix my error by avoiding empty `torch_geometric.data.Data` items